# How to handle spaces in path to a windows batch file?

Tags: java, batch-file, path

I have a batch file on windows machine.
The path to the same is having spaces in it. E.g. C:\Hello World\MyFile.bat

I am trying to execute the batch file through java as:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(dosCommand + destinationFilePath + batch)
```

But, as the path has spaces, it says "C:\Hello" is not a valid command or directory.

I tried this too:

Complete command: **`cmd /c start /wait "C:/Hello World/MyFile.bat"`** It opens the command prompt, but does not go to the folder Hello World and does not execute the bat file

How do I handle this situation.
Let me know if any additional Info. is required.

Comment: Try using [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve it using ProcessBuilder.
The directory in which the bat file is present can be added to the working directory as:

processBuilder.directory(new File("C:\hello world\"));

This works like gem.

```
    int result = 1;
    final File batchFile = new File("C:\\hello world\\MyFile.bat");
    final File outputFile = new File(String.format("C:\\hello world\\output_%tY%<tm%<td_%<tH%<tM%<tS.txt", System.currentTimeMillis()));

    final ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(batchFile.getAbsolutePath());
    processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
    processBuilder.redirectOutput(outputFile);
    processBuilder.directory(new File("C:\\hello world\\"));

    try {
        final Process process = processBuilder.start();
        if (process.waitFor() == 0) {
            result = 0;
        }
        System.out.println("Processed finished with status: " + result);
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using quotation marks (`"C:\Hello World\MyFile.bat"`) should do the trick. Within Java you'll have to secape the quotation marks with `\` (`String batch = "\"C:\Hello World\MyFile.bat\""`).

Comment: I tried exactly this too. Complete command: cmd /c start /wait "C:/Hello World/MyFile.bat" It opens the command prompt, but does not go to the folder Hello World and does not execute the bat file

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to escape quotes surrounding the path such as :

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(dosCommand + "\"" + destinationFilePath + batch + "\"")
```

Comment: I tried exactly this too. 
Complete command: cmd /c start /wait "C:/Hello World/MyFile.bat"
It opens the command prompt, but does not go to the folder Hello World and does not execute the bat file.

Comment: you have to use double backslashes instead of slashes in the file's path

Comment: did that too. does not work. same thing. opens cmd prompt. But, does not execute the batch. I have given the solution below.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this problem using a `ProcessBuilder` as well, however I gave the directory with a space to `processBuilder.directory` and ran the command with the bat file name.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "start", "/wait", "export.bat");

    pb.directory(new File(batDirectoryWithSpace));
    pb.redirectError();

    try {
        Process process = pb.start();
        System.out.println("Exited with " + process.waitFor());
    } 
    catch (IOException | InterruptedException ex) {
        Exceptions.printStackTrace(ex);
    }
```